# Limit Decimal Places in DBGrid

Tags: delphi, grid

I have a DBGrid which is connected to a ClientDataSet and it has a field UnitCost. What I want to do is to limit to 2 decimal places every value that will be assigned to that field. Is there an easier way to do this other than validating every input value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to set `ClientDataset.FieldByName('UnitCost').EditMask := '#.00';`

Comment: +1 for the EditMask as the OP seems interested in limiting input values (as opposed to just formatting the values for display).

Comment: How can I ged rid of the underscores and '.' in the grid because the grid by default has a value of __._?

Answer (score 3):

I usually use:

```
TFloatField(Myds.FieldByName('MyField')).DisplayFormat := '#.##';
```

This should work with every type of `TDataset`

Answer (score 1):

```
procedure TFMasterReport.DBDetail**DrawColumnCell**(Sender: TObject;
   const Rect: TRect; DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn;
   State: TGridDrawState);
begin
    TFloatField(Tempdtl.FieldByName('TS_Rate')).DisplayFormat := '0.000';
    TFloatField(Tempdtl.FieldByName('TS_Tvol')).DisplayFormat := '0.00';
    TFloatField(Tempdtl.FieldByName('TS_permit')).DisplayFormat := '0.00';
    TFloatField(Tempdtl.FieldByName('TS_tax')).DisplayFormat := '0.00';
    TFloatField(Tempdtl.FieldByName('TS_nettval')).DisplayFormat := '0.00';
end;
```