# How to limit decimal digits for a ftFloat field?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, masking

I need to limit the number of decimal digits that the user can type as value for a `ftFloat` field.

```
var
  Dst : TClientDataSet;
  Dsc : TDataSource;
  Fld : TNumericField;
  Edt : TDBEdit;
begin
  //dataset
  Dst := TClientDataSet.Create(Self);
  Dst.FieldDefs.Add('TEST', ftFloat);
  Dst.CreateDataSet();
  Dst.Active := True;
  Fld := Dst.Fields[0] as TNumericField;
  Dst.Append();
  Fld.AsFloat := 1234.56;
  Dst.Post();

  //field
  Fld.DisplayFormat := '0,.##'; //2 optional decimals, with thousands separator
  Fld.EditFormat := '0.##'; //2 optional decimals, withhout thousands separator

  //datasource
  Dsc := TDataSource.Create(Self);
  Dsc.DataSet := Dst;

  //control
  Edt := TDBEdit.Create(Self);
  Edt.DataSource := Dsc;
  Edt.DataField := Fld.FieldName;
  Edt.Top := 5;
  Edt.Left := 5;
  Edt.Parent := Self;
end;
```

In the example, after typing `1234,5678`, the `TDBEdit` control displays `1234,56` but the field's value is `1234,5678`.

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3715814/4528159), I've tried using the [`EditMask`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.MaskUtils.TEditMask) property.

```
Fld.EditMask := '9' + DecimalSeparator + '99;1; ';
```

Unfortunately this approach introduces several problems:

1. I can't set a variable number of digits for the integer part (e.g. values like `12`, `123`... can't be typed)
2. I can't set negative values (e.g. values like `-1`, `-12` can't be typed)
3. The decimal separator is always visible when editing.

   [image]

How can I avoid that the user types more than N digits in the decimal part (Without adding any other kind of limitation)?

Comment: You need to store the data as a decimal and not a base 2 float

Comment: Would it be an option to create a specific event handler or custom control (TDBEdit derived) for this, that validates the typed string? Or do you insist on having the handler with the field?

Comment: If you read the EditMask documentation you will see that you must use # instead of 9 to allow for a sign, and so, negative values. But I agree that edit masks are not a very user friendly way to handle input. I suggest you use the TField OnSetText to do the formatting.

Comment: @Frazz, aren't masks actually fixed? If I understood the question well, the OP wants to (except the possibility to enter minus sign) have also mask for limitless number of digits for the integral part and limited number of digits for the fractional part. Which I don't believe you can define with such mask.

Comment: @Frazz: I read that but `#` force the user to leave an empty space for positive numbers (which makes typing less comfortable and it doesn't solve the other problems)

Comment: @Victoria: yes, exactly

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I didn't understand what you mean, could you please explain more?

Comment: @H.Hasenack: Yes, I would like to do that at the field's level, possibly without adding event handlers

Comment: The numbers you want to store are likely currency values. They can't be exactly represented by base 2 floating point types. You should use a base 10 decimal representation.

Comment: `DisplayFormat` only affects the *display* of the data - it doesn't change the underlying representation. `EditFormat` only affects data entry - it doesn't change the underlying representation until you edit or insert and then type a new value into a DBEdit attached to the field. Neither property will change the data that is already in the field.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yes I know, I've learned that from my other questions. This time there are no currency values and I just need to make sure that the user specify a reasonable number of decimals when he types amounts of materials (e.g. the reasonable number of decimals is based on the kind of material and the unit of measurement), it's just for user's comfort reasons

Comment: Sounds very much like you are trying too hard in that case. Why not let the user decide for themselves how much precision they want?

Comment: In case of field based, i would suggest using the OnSetText event handler.. But I agree with David, why the restriction? Why not use a ftCurrency field, that's hard limited to a precision of 4 fractional digits. If you enter very (very!) large numbers it will get fractional +exponent storeage anyway.. Can you elaborate why exactly you need this functionality?

Comment: @H.Hasenack: Suppose the user types `0.014`, `0.024` and `0.034`. After post, he will see `0.01`, `0.02` and `0.03` but the sum of the values will display `0.07` and this could be a big problem for the user. Field events surely are the right place where to trunc extra decimals but it would be great if there were a property on the field for limiting the number of decimals and also stopping the user from typing more digits than needed

Answer (score 2):

Rather than avoiding typing the field extra digits, you can also strip the digits before they are posted to the datasaet.

Strip the "extra" digits on the TDataset.OnBeforePost event, or maybe better using the OnDataChange event of a TDatasource. (Pseudocode,untested)

```
procedure TSomeClass.OnDataChange(aField:TField)
begin
  if Assigned(aField) and (aField.FieldName='TEST') and not aField.IsNull then
    aField.AsFloat:=round(aField.AsFloat*100)/100.0;    
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

As I found nothing in standard VCL controls to achieve this, my approach would be to have a `TDBEdit` descendant that can be assigned desired `DecimalPlaces` and can then prohibit the user from entering more than configured.

This is independent of the underlying data-type, but for `ftFloat` it will try to convert the resulting value, eliminating e.g. multiple times decimalseperator.

This uses `KeyPress` to eliminate unwanted keys that would invalidate the current value, either adding too many decimal places or in case of `ftFloat` not being convertible by `TryStrToFloat`.

An example using sample then would be:

```
  //control
  Edt := TDecimalPlacesDBEdit.Create(Self);
  Edt.DataSource := Dsc;
  Edt.DataField := Fld.FieldName;
  Edt.Top := 5;
  Edt.Left := 5;
  Edt.Parent := Self;
  Edt.DecimalPlaces := 2;
```

Here is an implementation approach in a new unit:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Vcl.DBCtrls;

type
  TDecimalPlacesDBEdit = class(TDBEdit)
  private
    FDecimalPlaces: Integer;
    function IsValidChar(Key: Char): Boolean;
  protected
    procedure KeyPress(var Key: Char); override;
  public
    property DecimalPlaces: Integer read FDecimalPlaces write FDecimalPlaces;
  end;

implementation

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Data.DB,
  Winapi.Windows;

{ TDecimalPlacesDBEdit }

function TDecimalPlacesDBEdit.IsValidChar(Key: Char): Boolean;

  function IsValidText(const S: string): Boolean;
  var
    ADecPos, AStartPos: Integer;
    V: Double;
  begin
    Result := False;
    ADecPos := Pos(FormatSettings.DecimalSeparator, S);
    if ADecPos > 0 then
    begin
      AStartPos := Pos('E', UpperCase(S));
      if AStartPos > ADecPos then
        ADecPos := AStartPos - ADecPos - 1
      else
        ADecPos := Length(S) - ADecPos;
      if ADecPos > DecimalPlaces then
        Exit;
    end;
    if Assigned(Field) and (Field.DataType in [ftFloat{, ftSingle, ftExtended}]) then
      Result := TryStrToFloat(S, V)
    else
      Result := True;
  end;

var
  AEndPos, AStartPos: Integer;
  S: string;
begin
  Result := DecimalPlaces = 0;
  if not Result then
  begin
    S := Text;
    AStartPos := SelStart;
    AEndPos := SelStart + SelLength;
    // Prepare current Text as if the user typed his key, then check if still valid.
    Delete(S, SelStart + 1, AEndPos - AStartPos);
    Insert(Key, S, AStartPos + 1);
    Result := IsValidText(S);
  end;
end;

procedure TDecimalPlacesDBEdit.KeyPress(var Key: Char);
begin
  inherited KeyPress(Key);
  if (Key >= #32) and not IsValidChar(Key) then
  begin
    MessageBeep(0);
    Key := #0;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Unfortunately this would only work in this control. If the field would at the same time be available through e.g. an DBGrid, the user could still enter "too many"digits. In that case you may better use a BCD field instead of a float field which allows you to define the specifics better. Though I am NOT a fan of BCD fields I must say.

Comment: In that case I would apply a similar approach for `TDBGrid`: Own `TInplaceEdit` descendant, use `KeyPress` there, set `DecimalPlaces` in e.g. `UpdateContents`.

Comment: Feels like a bad idea having to implement the same code at multiple places. Maybe create a TFloatField descendent, and handle it in there? - adding your own field classes should not be too hard.

Comment: @H.Hasenack with the way EditMasks are implemented I feel like the way to control user input on a per character basis is the actual control, I don't think a `TField` class has enough info to do that with e.g. a `IsValidChar` override, as the current content of the editor is unknown to it. I don't like altering user input by rounding, so this is my approach.